# Creating universal mapping to close the current buffer without saving changes

Tags: vim

I'm trying to add a mapping to `vimrc` so if I press `\r` the current buffer will close without saving changes. I think `:enew!` is what I'd like to map but the way I've done it is wrong:

```
" Use Leader-r for closing the buffer without saving changes, also in Insert mode
nnoremap <Leader>r :<C-U>enew!<CR>
vnoremap <Leader>r :<C-U>enew!<CR>gv
cnoremap <Leader>r <C-C>:enew!<CR>
inoremap <Leader>r <C-O>:enew!<CR>
```

How do I amend the above?

*Edit*: As pointed out by glts what I'd actually like to do is discard the current buffer without saving changes

Comment: "close" buffer you mean "delete" the buffer or just "hide" the current?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having? The mappings work more or less fine.

Comment: @Kent ok - my misunderstanding - vim is ver new to me - yes now I realise that the buffer is just a copy of the actual file what I'd like to do is delete the buffer without saving changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the help states, `:enew!` discards changes made to the current buffer. Instead, use `:hide enew`, or, as many users prefer, `set hidden` in your vimrc and then just use `:enew`.

Or maybe what you actually meant was how to delete the current buffer without saving the changes? In that case, use `:bd!` instead of `:hide enew`.

```
nnoremap <Leader>r :<C-U>hide enew<CR>
xnoremap <Leader>r :<C-U>hide enew<CR>
cnoremap <Leader>r <C-C>:hide enew<CR>
inoremap <Leader>r <Esc>:hide enew<CR>
```

Personally I would advise against making such "universal" mappings. A normal mode mapping should be enough since a single <kbd>Esc</kbd> will take you there anyway.

---

An advanced solution suggested by @ZyX is to squeeze these four lines into one with this bit of `<C-\><C-N>` magic:

```
for a in ['n','x','c','i'] | exe a.'noremap <Leader>r <C-\><C-N>:hide enew<CR>' | endfor
```

Comment: +1 thanks glts. If I want to create a normal mode mapping for `:bd!` is it simply `nnoremap <Leader>r :<C-U>bd!<CR>` ....or does the exclamation mark need to be coded differently in `vimrc` ?

Comment: No problem. Yes, `nnoremap <Leader>r :<C-U>bd!<CR>` should work just like you wrote it.

Comment: what does the `<C-U>` bit do? ...in the original post some of the lines have colon then <C-U>, whereas for the c mode it is <C-C> followed by `:`?

Comment: It removes automatically inserted ranges. This is explained at [`:h omap-info`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#omap-info) (2nd paragraph). But a range can only be inserted automatically in normal and Visual mode, so these are the only places where it's needed. Read the chapter on mapping, `:h 40.1`.

Comment: @glts You can have one universal mapping for all modes at once if you use `<C-\><C-n>:hide enew<CR>`: it works identically for all modes, discarding a count in normal mode and switching to normal mode from any other mode via `<C-\><C-n>`. This way you can use a cycle and `:execute` to define all mappings without duplicating mapping rhs or lhs.

Comment: Terrific! Very useful information, thank you. I will add it to the answer.